# How do I make user confirm deletion before doing so in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms, ejs

I have a post request that must delete a record in mongodb, when submitted, but I need to confirm with the user before the instruction is executed in the mongodb. Here is what I have that isn't working:

```
// DeleteUser
router.post("/deleteUser", (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    function confirmDelete() {
        let result = confirm(
            "Are you sure that you want to delete " + allUsers[i].name + "?"
        );
        if (result) {
            // Delete Logic
           User.findOneAndDelete({ email: email }, (err) => {
               if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
               }
               console.log("One user deleted successfully!");
           });
        }
    }

    confirmDelete();

    setTimeout(res.redirect("back"), 5000);
});
```

I am getting an error that:

```
ReferenceError: confirm is not defined
```

I think `confirm()` is not a `node.js` function; It should be a browser object! How do I make this logic to pop a dialogue box to ask user to confirm delete; proceed when they click `Ok/Yes` and terminate when the click `Cancel`?

Answer (score 0):

That check / confirmation is a client-only thing. You cannot do that within your backend. If the request arrives you delete the user. The client can decide to display as many warnings and confirmation and alert boxes as they choose.

You *could* generate a unique token, send that to the client and only if the client submits a second request which includes that token only then actually delete the user. But you cannot guarantee that the client actually displays a confirmation box to the user before sending that second request, the client could just instantly submit the second request. And you end up where you started: the confirmation dialog is a client-only thing.